# Find the limit of : $\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{4x^2 + 3x - 1}{2x^3 + 9x +11}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit of $f(x) = \frac{4x^2 + 3x - 1}{2x^3 + 9x +11}$ as $x\to \infty$. The answer is $0$.

Divide each term by $x^3$, and then replace each $x$ with $\infty$:

$$\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{4x^2}{x^3} + \frac{3x}{x^3} - \frac{1}{x^3}}{\frac{2x^3}{x^3} + \frac{9x}{x^3} + \frac{11}{x^3}}$$

$$\lim _{x\to \infty} \frac{\frac{4}{x} + \frac{3}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^3}}{2 + \frac{9}{x^2} + \frac{11}{x^3}}$$

$$\lim _{x\to \infty} \frac{\frac{4}{\infty} + \frac{3}{\infty^2} + \frac{1}{\infty^3}}{2 + \frac{9}{\infty^2}+ \frac{11}{\infty^3}}$$

$$\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{ 0 + 0 + 0}{2 + 0 + 0} = \frac{0}{2} = 0$$

Is the answer 0 or no limit?

I'm asking, because there is a major typo in the book! The work shown is for the problem before this one.

Comment: The answer is indeed $0$.  But we don't "replace each $x$ with $\infty$.  We take the limit as $x\to \infty$.

Comment: Explain please?

Comment: Infinity is not a real number.

Comment: Indeed. Infinity in terms of limits is more of a behavior (you can say increasing) rather than a number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{4x^2 + 3x - 1}{2x^3 + 9x + 11} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{4/x + 3/x^2 - 1/x^3}{2 + 9/x^2 + 11/x^3}$

$\ = \dfrac{ \lim_{x\to\infty} ( 4/x + 3/x^2 - 1/x^3 ) }{ \lim _{x\to\infty} ( 2 + 9/x^2 + 11/x^3 ) }$   [because these two limits exists]

$\ = \dfrac{ \lim_{x\to\infty} 4/x + \lim_{x\to\infty} 3/x^2 - \lim_{x\to\infty} 1/x^3 }{ \lim _{x\to\infty} 2 + \lim_{x\to\infty} 9/x^2 + \lim_{x\to\infty} 11/x^3 }$   [because all these limits here exists]

$\ = \dfrac{0+0+0}{2+0+0}$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the solution is correct and also the deduction procedure.
Generally, for
\begin{equation}
\lim _{x\to \infty} \frac{ax^n +...}{bx^k + ..}
\end{equation}
whereas $n, k$ are the largest power of $x$ at the numerator and denominator parts, and $a, b$ are the coefficient number. We have

**(1) while $n>k$, the answer is $\infty$;**

**(2) while $n<k$, the answer is $0$**

**(3) while $n = k$, the answer is $\frac{a}{b}$**

Comment: And when $n=k$, the limit approaches a number $L$. Thought I add that :)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Thank you for this supplementary item

Comment: The solution is not correct! You cannot substitute the limiting variable under the limit. For example consider the **wrong** computations using that 'method': $1 = \lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{\frac{1}{x}-\frac1{x+1}}{1/x^2} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{\frac{1}\infty-\frac1{\infty+1}}{1/x^2} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{0}{1/x^2} = 0$; $\dfrac16 = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{k^2}{n^3} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{k^2}{\infty^3} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n 0 = 0$.